# how to read properties file in wso2 esb?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have written a proxy service in esb to read a file which i have stored in configuration registry and my proxy is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
           name="deleteme"
           transports="https http"
           startOnLoad="true"
           trace="disable">
       <description/>
       <target>
          <inSequence>
<property xmlns:p="http://tempuri.org/" name="SourceID" expression="//p:SourceID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
             <property name="test"
                       expression="get-property('registry','conf:/test.xml')"
                       scope="default"
                       type="OM"/>
             <property name="test.AddressEP" expression="$ctx:test//AddressEP"/>
             <log level="custom">
                <property name="test.AddressEP" expression="$ctx:test//AddressEP"/>
             </log>
             <header name="To" expression="get-property('test.AddressEP')"/>
             <send/>
          </inSequence>
       </target>
       <publishWSDL uri="http://pc241059:8281/services/echo?wsdl"/>
    </proxy>
```

Now instead of providing hard coded data **AddressEP** in the property:

```
<property name="test.AddressEP" expression="$ctx:test//AddressEP"/>
```

I want to pass the value of the property:

```
<property xmlns:p="http://tempuri.org/" name="SourceID" expression="//p:SourceID"/>
```

like

```
<property name="test.AddressEP" expression="$ctx:test//get-property('SourceID')"/>
```

But i am unable to do this?Please help me on this. Looking forward to your answers. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you still searching for the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is right[1] when you use path navigation, you need to use, functions which are working with tree model, like selecting nodes etc..(though im not sure)

In your case, you can simply use XPATh string merge functions..

[1]`<property name="test.AddressEP" expression="$ctx:test//get-property('SourceID')"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/retrieve-values-xml-config) can solve your problem.
It shows how to read from a xml file in the registry.